# ¿Por que cuando recorro el array en un forech, en el blade no me muestra toda la informacion del array?

Tags: php, html, laravel, array, web

Guardo en un array el contenido de un documento que pesa mas de 4,734KB y lo recorro con un foreach pero en el blade no muestra toda la info del array

## Muestro codigo del blade

```
@php
    $nNumPedimento = $nNumeroPedimento;
@endphp
@foreach ($aRegistrosM3 as $nIndex => $sValue)
<tr class=@php $sClassTabla = "tabla-".$nNumPedimento; echo $sClassTabla @endphp><td width="100%"><table width="100%" class="tablaM3">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
        <div class="row vertical-align" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
            <div class="col-xs-1 azul">
                <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right "></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-11 azul">
            &nbsp;<strong><a name=@php $sPedimentoName = $nNumPedimento."-".$nIndex; echo $sPedimentoName; @endphp><a name=@php echo $sPedimentoName; @endphp>{!! $aRegistrosM3[$nIndex]->GetEncabezado() !!}</a></a></strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
@php
    $aPartidasM3 = $aRegistrosM3[$nIndex]->GetRegistros();
    $nContadorRegistro = 1;
@endphp
@foreach ($aPartidasM3 as $nIndexPartida => $sValuePartida)
@php
    $nCuentaRegistros = count($aPartidasM3);
    if($aRegistrosM3[$nIndex]->GetTipo() == '500'){
        $nCuenta = 0;
    }else{
        $nCuenta = $nCuenta+1;
    }
@endphp
<tr><td class='sNombreCampo'>{{$nIndexPartida}}</td><td id="{{$nCuenta}}">
    <span id='@php $sRegiTr = "tr".$nNumPedimento."-".$aRegistrosM3[$nIndex]->GetTipo()."-".$nCuenta."-".$nContadorRegistro; echo $sRegiTr; @endphp'><span id='@php $sRegisTr = "tr".$nNumPedimento."-".$aRegistrosM3[$nIndex]->GetTipo()."-".$nIndex."-".$nContadorRegistro; echo $sRegisTr;  @endphp'>
    {{$sValuePartida}}</span></span></td></tr>
@php
    $nContadorRegistro++;
@endphp
@endforeach
</table></td></tr>
@endforeach
```

Ya hice aumento de memoria en el servidor y si hace el aumento.

Incluso detengo el el forech hasta cierto numero de de lineas y si se visualiza en el blade.

El maximo de lineas que ha recorrido es hasta 22000

## espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Si entiendo bien... ¿Quieres mostrar una tabla html con más de 22000 filas? Y si aumentas el límite de memoria, sí te deja mostrar más de 22000 filas

Comment: No puedes usar paginación?, la verdad tantos registros no es bueno enviarlos así

Comment: Con el limite de memoria solo puedo mostrar  hasta 22000 filas eso poniendo una condicion que se detenga hasta esa fila, ya despues de ese rango ya no se visualiza nada si dejo correr todo el array completo

Comment: Como tal es parte de un modulo donde trabajo, y los usuarios quieren la info en una sola pantalla, de hecho propuse que el archivo que se sube al servidor que es de donde obtengo el array tuviera un peso limite, pero esa no es una opcion por parte de la empresa, como tal debo mostrar todos los registros del array, pero gracias propondre hacer una paginacion